# Calls at the end of script execution are failing in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

We observed that while executing the below scenario, calls at the end of script execution are failing and they are counted as part of error %,

Scenario:

- Number of threads : 100 (even for 50 , 150 200 users, only the calls which are shown at the end of results tree are failing)
- Ramp up period : 5s
- Scheduler duration : 600s

[image]

We also observed that though the sceduled time is for 10mins(600s), jmeter runs for 11mins. Is there any option in jmeter for a ramp-down period?

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when JMeter forcibly terminates running threads, ideally that should not be happening and threads should be stopped gracefully.

The most possible reason is simply lack of resources as you are using JMeter in a not very correct way.

- [You should not use JMeter GUI for tests execution](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#load_test_running), GUI mode is only for tests development and debugging
- [You should not use any listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) during test execution. Run your test in non-GUI mode, store results into .jtl file and after test finishes either generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) or open the results file with the listener of your choice, but do this **after** test completion, not during the test.

With regards to "ramp-down" period: there are some custom Thread Groups available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project like [Stepping Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/) or [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which allow you to set up arbitrary rampdown patterns:

[image: Ultimate Thread Group]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Tried executing in non GUI mode , disabling listeners and observed that calls at the end are still failing. 

We have set the duration as 10 mins but  script executes for 10mins 37secs and calls in the last 37 seconds fails. I am new to Jmeter, , is this the way jmeter ends script execution is done ?

Comment: Anything suspicious in *jmeter.log* file? If threads are forcibly terminated - they will appear as errors in the results. You need to understand why threads cannot be shut down gracefully.